# How can i reorder data frame with many columns and rows according to vector with specific order?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, data-manipulation, pareto-chart

In R, I have two data frame and i need to reshape the first of according order with second df.

Using the actual data

Sheet 'Plan2'

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jkxik-QWz0kQYskQQXgaP0TXT7TsBLjp5RHSqtEw0pU/edit?usp=sharing

```
if(!require("FrF2")) install.packages("FrF2") ; library(FrF2)

df <- EXPERIMENTO_SALA <- read_excel("mypath/EXPERIMENTO SALA.xlsx", 
                           col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                         "numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                         "numeric", "numeric", "numeric"))


view(df)
print.data.frame(df)
```

The other data frame is:

```
plan.person = FrF2(nfactors = 5,
               resolution = 5,
               replications = 2,
               randomize = FALSE,
               factor.names = list(
                 pH = c(3, 9),
                 Temp = c(5, 30),
                 Dose = c(0.05, 0.5),
                 Conc = c(50, 350),
                 Speed = c(100, 200)
               ))

view(plan.person)
```

Note that data frames are similar. This is because i am replicating a studying for to practice the R software for experiment analysis. The big difference is that em 'df' i have three responses for this experiment and there is also difference in the rows organized.

I need to reshape the data frame 'df' for to make it equal to the data frame 'plan.person', however I need to be three frame data 'plan.person' (plan.person1, plan.person2, plan.person3), one for each response under analysis (% removal of SMO,% removal of CO,% removal of Bright-Edge 80) that are in the data fram 'df'.

Please, how can I do this?

** I present a more general example using toy data using a smaller example.

```
if(!require("FrF2")) install.packages("FrF2") ; library(FrF2)
if(!require("truncnorm")) install.packages("truncnorm") ; library(truncnorm)

plan.person = FrF2(nfactors = 3,
               resolution = 3,
               replications = 2,
               randomize = FALSE,
               factor.names = list(
                 Temp = c(5, 30),
                 Conc = c(50, 350),
                 Speed = c(100, 200)
               ))

Temperatura <- c(5, 5, 30, 30, 5, 5, 30, 30)
Concentracao <- c(350, 50, 350, 50, 350, 50, 350, 50)
Velocidade <- c(100, 200, 200, 100, 100, 200, 200, 100)

remov_SMO <- rtruncnorm(n=8, a=0, mean=61.16, sd=31.32)
remov_CO <- rtruncnorm(n=8, a=0, mean=79, sd=24.17)
remov_BE <- rtruncnorm(n=8, a=0, mean=71.43, sd=29.61)


df <- data.frame(Temperatura, Concentracao, Velocidade, remov_SMO,
            remov_CO, remov_BE)


view(df)
view(plan.person)
```

In this smaller example, I need to sort the row of the data frame 'df' in the same way as the data frame 'plan.person' according to the Temperatura (= Temp), Concentracao (= Conc) and Velocidade (= Speed) information, to organize the experiment responses so that you can continue to use the FrF2 package.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaWd3.png

Comment: Rather than presenting your problem using your real data, possibly you could present a more general example using toy data. It makes easier to understand your problem.

Comment: ok, i ll edit this post and increase this.

Comment: Hi, @Hugo, I edited, I think it was similar, but smaller.

Comment: I don't have `truncnorm` installed, nor do I want to install it. Does your example really need that specific funciton? Maybe you can just use `rnorm` in this example... Similarly, I don't know about `FrF2`, is it being used? Seems like you don't need to tell us to install it for this example.

Comment: @Gregor, To generate experimental planning, I need the FrF2 package. And the truncnorm package allows me to easily get values similar to rnorm, but with a = 0 i its the minimum possible value generated will be zero.

Comment: The question isn't if **you** need those packages for your analysis, the question is do **we** need those packages to answer your question.  I see now how the FrF2 is being used in the simple example, but it seems like `rnorm` could stand in for `rtruncnorm` for the purposes of illustration.

Comment: @Gregor, see it: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S4ldXqiURXedur7QSqveSd-dPK6zz7c4MkU3g8xgVOo/edit?usp=sharing

Alexis make it, its working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order is what matters, and you have duplicate combinations, I think it's easier to order both data frames, bind them, and then return to the original order:

```
df <- data.frame(Temperatura,
                 Concentracao,
                 Velocidade,
                 remov_SMO, remov_CO, remov_BE)


reorder_ids <- do.call(order, as.list(plan.person))
plan_ordered <- plan.person[reorder_ids,]
df_ordered <- df[do.call(order, as.list(df[, 1:3])),]

new_plan <- data.frame(plan_ordered, df_ordered[, -(1:3)])
new_plan <- new_plan[reorder_ids,] # restore original order
attributes(new_plan) <- attributes(plan.person)
```

I think `new_plan` should have what you want, but you might have to adjust column names.

EDIT: I would be particularly careful with the output attributes,
it seems to me that `plan.person` has quite a few extras added by `FrF2`,
and other functions might depend on them.

Comment: dont worked. I would like 'df' to have the same configuration of the data frame 'plan.person', so that I continue using the FrF2 package, because the next step is the function 'add.response', where I will generate three experimental analyzes [ one for each response].

Comment: You mean the same order? Yeah that will be trickier because you have duplicated combinations...

Comment: yeah, this is all to try to make the most reproducible possible for other people to use in other experimental analyzes. It has duplicates because the experiment was done in duplicate.
https://i.imgur.com/DQBHQNi.png

Comment: Hey, @Alexis, thanks!!! It worked!
I thought the solution would be by match () or something elegant from tidyverse, but its solution helped me a lot!
See here using the actual data.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1S4ldXqiURXedur7QSqveSd-dPK6zz7c4MkU3g8xgVOo/edit?usp=sharing